# Associate external content source with list item

Tags: 2013, search, visual-studio, search-results

I have a custom list with URL column. This URL will be used for crawling external content (e.g. network folder) and I'd like to associate search results with this list item.

e.g. Search result contains a document. Url for this document specified in list item and i'd like to display this list item in search results instead of the document itself.

Is it possible?

Thank you all in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I would crawl the list (best case is create a new content type for the list item.) Then create a display template that shows the details you prefer and associate a Result Type rule for the content type to show the display template.